# ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [2], [2,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm so news to Tensorflow . I already search for same questions,but i can't understand. there is the code .Hope you can help me.

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,3],stddev=1,seed=1))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3],stddev=1,seed=1))

x = tf.constant([0.7,0.9])

a = tf.matmul(x, w1)
y = tf.matmul(a, w2)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(w1.initializer)
sess.run(w2.initializer)

print(sess.run(y))
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

The shape of constant `x` is `(2,)`, i.e. a one-dimensional array, and you are trying to multiply it with a two-dimensional array `w1` of shape `(2, 3)`, which is not possible for matrix multiplication, as number of columns of first parameter must be equal to number of rows in second parameter. Also, I think `tf.matmul` only works if both arrays are two-dimensional.

One of the many ways you can change your declaration of `x` as

`x = tf.constant([[0.7], [0.9]])`

This will create a two-dimensional constant tensor of shape (2, 1). And, then multiply it as,

`a = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), w1)`

`tf.transpose()` is used to create transpose of array x with shape (2, 1) to shape (1, 2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: _Also, I think tf.matmul only works if both arrays are two-dimensional._ - Thanks, this was my issue

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the rank of variable x is 1. Hence the issue.

Following is the reason you are having this issue.

Please refer the tensorflow API https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul

tf.matmul(**a, b**, transpose_a=False, transpose_b=False, adjoint_a=False, adjoint_b=False,
    a_is_sparse=False, b_is_sparse=False, name=None)

**Args:**

a: Tensor of type float16, float32, float64, int32, complex64, complex128 and ***rank > 1***.

b: Tensor with ***same type and rank*** as a.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of `x` is `(2,)` does not match the shape `(2,3)` of `w1`.

You should change

```
x = tf.constant([0.7,0.9])
```

to

```
x = tf.constant([[0.7,0.9]])
```

now the shape of `x` is `(1,2)` and works fine.